# Compiler Error in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile this code.  It is giving me this error:

```
format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **' [-Werror,-Wformat]
```

on all my `%s`'s.  What could it be? This is an example from a book.  Thanks for any help.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main(void) {
    int response;
    char *lName[20] = {0};
   char *fName[20] = {0};
   char *number[20] = {0};
   FILE *pWrite;
   FILE *pRead;
    printf("\n\tPhone Book\n");
    printf("\n1\tAdd phone book entry\n");
    printf("2\tPrint phone book\n\n");
    printf("Select an option: ");
    scanf("%d", &response);
    if ( response == 1 ) {
      scanf("%s", fName);
   printf("\nEnter last name: ");
   scanf("%s", lName);
   printf("\nEnter phone number: ");
   scanf("%s", number);
   pWrite = fopen("phone_book.dat", "a");
   if ( pWrite != NULL ) {
      fprintf(pWrite, "%s %s %s\n", fName, lName, number);
      fclose(pWrite);
 } else
 goto ErrorHandler; 
  } 
 else if ( response == 2 ) {

   pRead = fopen("phone_book.dat", "r");
   if ( pRead != NULL ) {
    printf("\nPhone Book Entries\n");
    while ( !feof(pRead) ) {
    fscanf(pRead, "%s %s %s", fName, lName, number);
    if ( !feof(pRead) )
       printf("\n%s %s\t%s", fName, lName, number);
       } 
      printf("\n");
    }
      else
       goto ErrorHandler;  
     }
     else {
      printf("\nInvalid selection\n");
   }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
   ErrorHandler:
      perror("The following error occurred");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
     } //end main
```

Comment: Please don't tell me the book used that indentation and lack of spacing. Anyway, you're giving an array of `char *` to `fprintf`, but saying you'll pass a (`const`) `char *` with `%s`. And you're really opening yourself up to easy buffer overruns with the input not stopping at the end of the array. And none of the input is checked. Just because `feof` says you aren't at the end doesn't mean the next read will be successful.

Comment: [Explanation of why `while( !feof(pRead) )` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

As you can probably guess, something here is wrong:

```
char *lName[20] = {0};
char *fName[20] = {0};
char *number[20] = {0};
```

You see, when you declare an array like this:

```
int a[20];
```

what you're saying to the compiler is: "Give me an array with 20 ints, and make the variable "a" point to the beginning of them". It's like saying `a` is actually an `int*`, not an int. So, if you declare

```
int* a[20];
```

What you're declaring is an array of "pointers to integers". It's like `a` is an `int**`, also not an int.

Applying that to your problem:

```
char lName[20] = {0};
char fName[20] = {0};
char number[20] = {0};
```

You see, now it's declaring 3 arrays of chars, and the variables lName, fName and number will point to the beginning of the arrays and have type `char*`, as is expected by `scanf`when you use `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

Your allocating pointers.

This

```
char *lName[20] = {0};
char *fName[20] = {0};
char *number[20] = {0};
```

should be this

```
char lName[20] = {0};
char fName[20] = {0};
char number[20] = {0};
```

Comment: Or, more simply, `char lName[20] = "";`. Or perhaps they're supposed to be arrays of `char*` pointers, and you need to call `scanf` with an element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a typing error.

```
char *lName[20] = {0};
```

It should be

```
char lName[20] = {0};
```

Similar changes should be made to the definitions of `fName` and `number`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *lName[Val] = {0};
char *fName[Val] = {0};
char *number[Val] = {0};
```

are equivalent to two dimensional array. But you are using it as one dimensional array. Just do the following

```
char lName[20] = {0};
char fName[20] = {0};
char number[20] = {0};
```

And it will solve your problem.